# A5 paper size (twoside) AMS book class

Tags: books, double-sided, paper-size, amsbook

I am using the AMS book class for writing a thesis. While the first draft was required to be submitted on A4 paper size, the final version needs to be provided on (twoside) A5 paper size. Is there a simple way of changing the paper size within the AMS book class?

Within the preamble

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,twoside]{amsbook}
```

it appears that neither the "a5paper" option nor the "twoside" option (flushing the text somewhat left and right) is supported. Help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `amsbook` class is compatible with `geometry`.

```
\documentclass{amsbook}
\usepackage[
  a5paper,
  twoside,
]{geometry}

\usepackage{kantlipsum}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\begin{titlepage}

The title of the thesis
and all paraphernalia

\end{titlepage}

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\kant[1-5]

\chapter{First}

\kant[2]

\section{Abc}

\kant[3-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Adjust widths and margins to your (or the faculty's) tastes.